# Problems erasing an int from a vector of ints

Tags: c++, vector, int, erase, const-iterator

My objective is to have a large global vector of ballistics objects to keep track of every shot/bullet/missile currently active.  However, I also need each tile to know which ballistic object is directly above it (for rendering purposes), so I'm trying to make each tile have a small vector of ints, each being an index into the larger BallistsVector to describe which ones are above it at any given frame

My problem is I'm trying to erase an int from a vector of ints, however I keep getting:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" matches the argument list

std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>> std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>,std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>
```

I have:

```
extern std::vector<BallisticObject> BallisticVector;
```

I have tile.h:

```
class Tile
{
public:
    Tile(float height, char type);
    ~Tile();
    unsigned char myType;
    float myHeight;
    //future optimization: change below to forward_list
    std::vector<int> Indices_of_Ballistic_Objects_Above_Me;
};
```

I have a snippet from BallisticsObject.cpp:

```
void BallisticObject::Explode()
{
int TileOverX = location.x / 64;
int TileOverY = location.y / 64;

if (TileOverX >= 0 && TileOverX < MAP_WIDTH && TileOverY >= 0 && TileOverY < MAP_HEIGHT) //if it's within bounds
    if (location.z <= Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->myHeight + 1.0f) //if it's close to the ground
    {
        this->active = 0;
        Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->myHeight -= 1.0f; //chip away at the ground

        //now look through the vector of integers (which are indices into the global ballistics vector) and find myself (one that matches my own index)
        for (int i = 0; i < Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->Indices_of_Ballistic_Objects_Above_Me.size(); i++)
        {
            if (Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->Indices_of_Ballistic_Objects_Above_Me[i] == myIndex) //found myself
            {
                //remove myself from the tile's list of ballistics object that are above it
                Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->Indices_of_Ballistic_Objects_Above_Me.erase(i);
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "Error: ballistics object couldn't find itself in the tile's vector of indices!\n";
        }

    }
}
```

I have a nagging feeling that I'm either doing one tiny thing wrong, or one huge thing wrong...

Comment: You must pass an iterator - the quick but messy hack is `Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->Indices_of_Ballistic_Objects_Above_Me.erase(Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->Indices_of_Ballistic_Objects_Above_Me.begin()+i);`

Comment: ..and just like that, it compiled immediately and ran!
  Thank you so much!

Comment: For the future, please try to reduce your description and the code to focus on your question. It really doesn't matter that we're talking about the bullets here, and also, the relevant code is just a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Erase-remove_idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
auto& v = Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->Indices_of_Ballistic_Objects_Above_Me;

v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), myIndex));
```

And if you want to check for missing value, you might do:

```
auto& v = Map[TileOverX][TileOverY]->Indices_of_Ballistic_Objects_Above_Me;
auto old_size = v.size();

v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), myIndex));
if (old_size == v.size()) {
     std::cout <<
        "Error: ballistics object couldn't find itself in the tile's vector of indices!\n";
}
```